# Elixir what is a best practice when you want to use `when` but with a couple of conditions?

Tags: elixir

I am trying to learn elixir and I am wondering about `when`.

If I have a struct, and I want to do something when say `is_member` is true and `level` is greater than 10, how can I handle that?

```
def allow_entry(%Player{ is_member: is_member, level: level })
  when ((the conditions above))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`when` works with any kind of boolean expression, no different from any other pattern matching in Elixir.

```
defmodule Player do
  defstruct is_member: nil, level: nil
end

defmodule TestModule do

  def allow_entry(%Player{ is_member: true, level: level }) 
    when level > 10 do
    IO.inspect(["Success"!, is_member, level])
  end

  def test() do
    # allow_entry(%Player{ is_member: true, level: 0}) # This will fail
    allow_entry(%Player{ is_member: true, level: 15}) # This will succeed
    # allow_entry(%Player{ is_member: false, level: 0}) # This will fail
    # allow_entry(%Player{ is_member: false, level: 15}) # This will fail
  end
end

TestModule.test()
```

Comment: oh wow... I realize I was trying to use `&&` :(  i need to read the basics :(  thanks!

Comment: You can read more about it here. http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/case-cond-and-if.html

Comment: Btw, for future questions, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to save others from having to mock up your data structures.

Comment: sorry!  will do.  much appreciated!

Comment: FYI, you don't really need the is_member to be a guard clause. Just pattern match in the method i.e. def allow_entry(%Player{ is_member: true, level: level })

Comment: @owen OOoo, true!